# Google Map Isolate Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, flutter-layout

As you know Google Map initializing is very slow and janky. Every process is stop when Google Map initializing. Can we achieve by using isolate ? Or any idea about solve Google Map jank ? How can we make build and draw things in Isolate ?